# How to add Hover functionality using javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element which is a canvas element made up of a bunch of images. I want to add a label to each image on the canvas but only want it to show up when the user hovers over the correct image.

I have managed to get some text to show up but I cant work out how only to show it on mouseover and to not show on mouseleave. Currently I am checking to see if the mouse position matches the mouse position of the points array. If it does it adds the text.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove.bind(this));


var handleMouseMove = function (e) {
    var mousePos = getSquare(canvas, e);
    var pos = points.filter((item => mousePos.x === item.x && mousePos.y === item.y));
    if (pos && pos.length) {
      context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
      console.log(pos);
      context.fillText('Hello', pos[0].x, pos[0].y);
    } else {
      context.fillStyle = "#ffffff00";
      return;
    }
  };

  var getSquare = function (canvas, evt) {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: 1 + (evt.clientX - rect.left) - (evt.clientX - rect.left) % 20,
      y: 1 + (evt.clientY - rect.top) - (evt.clientY - rect.top) % 20
    };
  };
```

Essentially I want the 'Hello' to show up but only when you are hovering over the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

This is classic intersection, you have to compare the x and y position of the mouse to the x, y, width and height of the images on the canvas. If they intersect, show the label.

You can do this with some relatively simple math, or use the [isPointInPath](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_ispointinpath.asp) function for this.

Some super simple pseudo code, there are better/neater ways of doing this;

```
image = x20,y50,w200,h100
mouse = x30,y40

if  mouse.x >= image.x
and mouse.x <= image.x + image.width
and mouse.y >= image.y
and mouse.y <= image.y + image.height {
    // mouse is over image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can save the canvas to data(maybe base64.) Thus when the user mouseout, redraw the canvas from the data of store.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that can use multiple tips for your images:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var points = [
  {x: 10, y: 20}, 
  {x: 100, y: 50}
];
var images = [{
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/40', 
    tip: 'Hello',
    width: 40, height: 40
  }, {
    src: 'https://via.placeholder.com/80x50',
    tip: 'Another Image',
    width: 80, height: 50
  }
];
var drawImages = function () {
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  images.forEach(function (item, index) {
    if (item.img) {
      context.drawImage(item.img, points[index].x, points[index].y);
    } else {
      item.img = new Image();
      item.img.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(item.img, points[index].x, points[index].y);
      }
      item.img.src = item.src;
    }
  }); 
};

drawImages();

var handleMouseMove = function (e) {
  drawImages();
  var mousePos = getSquare(canvas, e);
  var pos = points.filter((item, index) => (
    (mousePos.x >= item.x && mousePos.x <= item.x + images[index].width ) &&
    (mousePos.y >= item.y && mousePos.y <= item.y + images[index].height)
  ));
  if (pos && pos.length) {
    var index = points.indexOf(pos[0]);
    context.fillText(images[index].tip, mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
  }
};

var getSquare = function (canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: 1 + (evt.clientX - rect.left),
    y: 1 + (evt.clientY - rect.top)
  };
};


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove.bind(this));
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #000}
```

```html
<canvas>No canvas support</canvas>
```